# Issue with multiple bootstrap-multiselect on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

On Page I have 3 [multiple-select-boxes](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). Only for 3rd one I have additional logic (custom `onchange` event). 
So first 2 I just initialize with line of code :

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect();
```

But when I've tried to add custom logic for 3rd select - it doesn't work.

```
$('#RegionIds').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
        alert('changed value' + $(option).val());
    }
});
```

Alert never appears in this case.

---

Update : JsBIN Example : https://jsbin.com/voquhegode/edit?html,js,output

---

Update 2 :

Thanks for replies. But I've found another issue with multiple selects.

https://jsfiddle.net/x6z6w0n8/7/ In case I want to set selected values on initialize step, I saw one additional select. This causes line of code where I manualy set selected values

```
$(select).multiselect('select', jsonArr[i].Item1);
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, JSBIN example will be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **$('.multiselect').multiselect();** in the end like here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/x6z6w0n8/6/) Because you cover other elements with custom logic which has the same class .multiselect

```
$('#example-onInitialized').multiselect({  
  onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
    var changedVal = $(option).val();
    if (changedVal < 3) {
      if (checked == true) {
        console.log('less');
      } else if (checked == false) {
        console.log('more');
      }
    }
  }
});
$('#RegionIds').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
        console.log('changed');
    }
});
$('.multiple').multiselect();
```

Or if every select has custom logic call multiselect() for concret IDs.

Comment: In this case My select is empty... Try to find problem. And could you also check my "Update 2" Thanks

Comment: Update2: Here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/qtx8bLgp/12/ with preselected values.